# Installing Cocos2D - iPhone for non-admin using root account

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm a high school student taking an iPhone development class. For my final project I was hoping to use cocos2d to make a game. My teacher has no problem with this, but we cannot access terminal from my student account. However, my teacher does have access to the root account on our computer (running OS X 10.6.8 I think).

My question is: How do we use the computer's root account to install cocos2d so that my non-administrator account can use it in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just [install Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) which includes Cocos2D and uses a proper installer package. You need to enter the root password once during installation, and the files are placed in the user's home folder ~/Kobold2D.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking root access is required only to install XCode templates. All you need is to create empty project from the scratch, add library manually to the project and copy boilerplate code from somewhere else + adjust project settings.

Another way - pick up any cocos2d open-source app ( like https://github.com/kayrules/Cocos2d-Endless-Platformer-Game/tree/master/EndlessPlatformer for instance ). Since its already include library all you need is to delete all non relevant code.